# Is Starbound the sequel to Terraria? or what is their relationship?

Tags: terraria, starbound

A game called 'Starbound' popped up on Steam and I am confused as I am waiting for Terraria 2.

I love Terraria and some various websites said that the Starbound developer team has members from the Terarria team.  Also terraria 2 and starbound are both supposed to feature infinite worlds and space travel etc.

1. Is starbound terraria 2? or are they different competitor companies / games?
2. Is starbound game play similar to terraria?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Starbound is from a different developer, only [@Tiyuri](https://twitter.com/Tiyuri) worked on both games. Starbound is quite similar to Terraria, but there are a few key differences such as races and the fact that the world doesn't end, it wraps around (planets are round, you can walk in one direction and end up where you started).

Starbound is not a sequel, but many people call it a *spiritual successor* to Terraria.

The gameplay is similar, and the key differences come from Starbound's questing, spaceships and the ability to travel between planets within the game. This is extremely useful for public multiplayer servers, who don't need to worry about players stealing from others anymore and most random people are unlikely to even see each other by chance. Other than that, most mechanics are just the same old polished up a bit with a new look.

Answer (score 7):

No, Starbound is not a sequel to Terraria.

Answer (score 1):

Starbound is an idea that may well been motivated by Terraria but was in no way meant to replace or continue Terraria.

There is definitely a plan to make Terraria 2. However, whether it is still in the planning phase or is being worked on right now I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Starbound  is not a sequel to Terraria, and Terraria's sequel (Otherworld) has been cancelled. Loki said this why it was cancelled here > https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/this-is-the-end-otherworld-development-cancelled.68594/

Comment: do you have anything (sites/dev tweets etc.) to support your answer?

Comment: @Malco on the steam the most recent news is Terraria otherworld being cancelled. Also, Loki posted this > https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/this-is-the-end-otherworld-development-cancelled.68594/ <.

Comment: That is pretty relevant, you should consider expanding on your answer by including those sources.

Answer (score -1):

Both games share key similarities but Starbound has more of an emphasis on questing and NPC interaction. Terraria does to an extent but its mostly about surviving