# Can you mine through the world?

Tags: starbound

As mentioned [in this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/144826/39891) the world in starbound loops around.

Can I keep digging down and end up on the other side of the world? What happens when I keep digging down?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you dig down, you will reach bottom. Your screen will stop scrolling.

[image: Bottom of world]

Source: [reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com/r/starbound/comments/1s7npv/we_learned_how_to_erase_lava_and_so_we_journeyed/)

Comment: and then if you mine sideways from that you can wrap around again, I guess

Comment: I think so, it will require a lot of blocks.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't. You can walk around a planet though, so when you walk to the west or east for long enough, you'll once again arrive at your starting point. As far as I know you'll hit an unpenetrable border, so the planets are essentially rings; at least when considering the accessible parts.

Comment: If they were rings, then instead of an unpenetrable border at the bottom there'd be a huge empty space.

Comment: Well, that really depends on how the "bottom" is made/interpretated. It's just solid and you can't get below. Since the left/right will wrap, you're essentially moving on a ring you can't break through.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not go straight through, when you are near the bottom, there is a giant magma pool. This is the core. You can use blocks to keep going further, but this is not recommended, as when the screen stops scrolling, if you touch the bottom of the screen, it is insta-death.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more of the mantle of the planet? The core is usally solid.